# PHP Loop with dropdown selection and submit button?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, menu

I am trying to make a loop that gets the name some other info about a product from a sql table - [MySQL table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODs9I.jpg)

Then Creates a page that looks like that - [Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZj1F.jpg)

So Far I have this code that does show it but I cant figure out a way how to update the name of the dropdown menu so when I press submit It writes into another SQL table the name of the product and then how many of those products did the customer selected .

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM product";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
 $columnValues[] = $row['ProductID'];           
foreach($columnValues as $key => $value) {
$$key = $value;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr>\n". "<br>";
echo "##product-ID## ";
echo "<td>".$row['ProductID']. "</td>\n";                           
echo "  ##product-name## ";
echo "<td>".$row['ProductName']."</td>\n";                          
echo "<td>\n";                              
echo "  ##dropdown## ";
echo "<select id=$value>\n";
echo "<option value='1'>1</option>\n";
echo "<option value='2'>2</option>\n";
echo "<option value='3'>3</option>\n";
echo "<option value='4'>4</option>\n";
echo "<option value='5'>5</option>\n";
echo "<option value='6'>6</option>\n";
echo "</select>\n";
echo "</td>\n";     
echo "</tr>\n";
 } 
    } 
        }

        $conn->close();                         
?>
<html>
 <body>
<form method="POST" action="#" >
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /><br>
</form>                                             </body>
</html>
```

I know I will most likely need a second php script for the capture of the post so help with that will be greatly appreciated too .

////////////////////////////////////////////////

So up to here I got it somehow - It loops and shows all the product . When I press submit it adds only the last product in the loop and it doesn't care of the drop down menu - Just adds a "2" .

The table where the script writes is simple - 4 columns OrderID1,productid1,ProductName1 orderedqnt1

Thanks in advance .

### Index.php

```
<html>
<body>
  <form method="POST" action="insert.php" >
<?php

session_start(); // session start for Variables to add to the sql in Insert.php
include("global.php"); // Stores the session Variables

## Conection part 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM product";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

  $columnValues[] = $row['ProductID'];
  foreach($columnValues as $key => $value) {
    $$key = $value;

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo "<tr>\n". "<br>";
  echo "##product-ID## ";
  echo "<td>".$row['ProductID']. "</td>\n";
  echo "  ##product-name## ";
  echo "<td>".$row['ProductName']."</td>\n";
  echo "<td>\n";
  /* echo "  ##dropdown## "; */

  echo "<select id=" . $value . " name='dropdown'>\n";  

  echo "<option value=''>-</option>\n";
  echo "<option value='1'>1</option>\n";
  echo "<option value='2'>2</option>\n";
  echo "<option value='3'>3</option>\n";
  echo "<option value='4'>4</option>\n";
  echo "<option value='5'>5</option>\n";
  echo "<option value='6'>6</option>\n";
  echo "</select>\n";
  /* echo "</td>\n"; */
  /* Echo ":::::value variable = "."$value"; */
  echo "</tr>\n" . "<br>";

print_r ($value);


  $_SESSION['GrabIDses']=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$row['ProductID']);  //Grabs the ID of the product in Session Variable
  $_SESSION['GrabNameses']=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$row['ProductName']); //Grabs the Name of the product in Session Variable
  $_SESSION['GrabSKUses']=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$row['SKU']); //Grabs the SKU of the product in Session Variable
  $_SESSION['Ordered']=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value); //Grabs the Ordered Quantity for  the product in Session Variable ????????????????

  /* $GrabID = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$row['ProductID']);
  $GrabName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$row['ProductName']);
  $GrabSKU = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$row['SKU']);
  echo "----------------------"."$_SESSION['GrabSKUses']"."<br>"."$_SESSION['GrabIDses']"."<br>"."----------------------"; */

    }
  }
}
$conn->close();
echo "<br>";
?>

<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /><br>
  </form>
</body>
```

---

### Insert.php

```
  <?php
session_start(); // session start

$getvalue = $_SESSION['GrabIDses']; // session get
$getvalue1 = $_SESSION['GrabNameses']; // session get
$getvalue2 = $_SESSION['GrabSKUses']; // session get
$ordered11 = $_SESSION['Ordered']; // session get

echo $getvalue;
echo "||";
echo $getvalue1; 
echo "||";
echo $getvalue2;
echo "||"."<br>";
print_r($_SESSION);

## Connection Part
   if(isset($_POST['dropdown'])) {

        echo("You order was completed" . "<br>");           
        $sql = "INSERT INTO testorder (productid1,ProductName1,orderedqnt1) VALUES ('$getvalue', '$getvalue1','$ordered11')";



        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) 
            { echo "New record created successfully"; }     

        else 
            { echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn); }
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }

else {
echo" dhur";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<select id=$value>\n";
```

needs a name. So change to

```
echo "<select id=" . $value . " name='dropdown'>\n";
```

Then you need to make a second page, use

```
if(isset($_POST['dropdown'])) {
```

Then insert or update table with the info. I think you can get this part down quite easily :).

Edit:

```
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

$columnValues[] = $row['ProductID'];
foreach($columnValues as $key => $value) {
$$key = $value;

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

You're using 2 while loops. That's 1 to many.

Comment: It just loops but it writes only the very last product in the loop

Comment: Are you using multiselect in the dropdown?

Comment: Changed it and it got worse :) . I will probably abandon this and try to make it in a different manner completely.

Answer (score 0):

The < select>-Boxes have to be inside the form and inside the web page at all.

Enter a name-attribute in the < select>-Tag, to make the data available in the saving script vie $_POST

I am not sure, what you want to do, so I don't know if $row['ProductID'] is a reasonable name.

```
<html>
<body>
  <form method="POST" action="#" >
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password ="";
$dbname = "company";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM product";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
  $columnValues[] = $row['ProductID'];
  foreach($columnValues as $key => $value) {
    $$key = $value;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "<tr>\n". "<br>";
      echo "##product-ID## ";
      echo "<td>".$row['ProductID']. "</td>\n";
      echo "  ##product-name## ";
      echo "<td>".$row['ProductName']."</td>\n";
      echo "<td>\n";
      echo "  ##dropdown## ";
      echo "<select id='$value' name='{$row['ProductID']}'>\n";
      echo "<option value='1'>1</option>\n";
      echo "<option value='2'>2</option>\n";
      echo "<option value='3'>3</option>\n";
      echo "<option value='4'>4</option>\n";
      echo "<option value='5'>5</option>\n";
      echo "<option value='6'>6</option>\n";
      echo "</select>\n";
      echo "</td>\n";
      /* Echo ":::::value variable = "."$value"; */
      echo "</tr>\n";
    }
  }
}
$conn->close();
?>

    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /><br>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
<body>
  <form method="POST" action="#" >
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password ="";
$dbname = "company";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM product";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
  $columnValues[] = $row['ProductID'];
  foreach($columnValues as $key => $value) {
    $$key = $value;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "<tr>\n". "<br>";
      echo "##product-ID## ";
      echo "<td>".$row['ProductID']. "</td>\n";
      echo "  ##product-name## ";
      echo "<td>".$row['ProductName']."</td>\n";
      echo "<td>\n";
      echo "  ##dropdown## ";
      echo "<select id='$value' name='{$row['ProductID']}'>\n";
      echo "<option value='1'>1</option>\n";
      echo "<option value='2'>2</option>\n";
      echo "<option value='3'>3</option>\n";
      echo "<option value='4'>4</option>\n";
      echo "<option value='5'>5</option>\n";
      echo "<option value='6'>6</option>\n";
      echo "</select>\n";
      echo "</td>\n";
      /* Echo ":::::value variable = "."$value"; */
      echo "</tr>\n";
    }
  }
}
$conn->close();
?>

    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /><br>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```